# Enable Extensions for PHP on Centos 7

Tags: php, module

I want to run Drupal using Ngnix, but once I've installed ngnix, drupal, I see this:

```
Drupal requires you to enable the PHP extensions in the following list 
(see the system requirements page for more information):
 dom
 gd
 pdo
```

I have php script that shows these modules aren't loaded:

```
<?php
 $dom = extension_loaded( 'dom');
 $gd = extension_loaded( 'gd');
 $pdo = extension_loaded( 'pdo');
 echo '<p>Hello Bogus Drupal, from Tommy the Geek</p>';
 echo "GD: ", extension_loaded('gd') ? 'OK' : 'MISSING', '<br>';
 echo "dom: ", extension_loaded('dom') ? 'OK' : 'MISSING', '<br>';
 echo "PDO: ", extension_loaded('pdo') ? 'OK' : 'MISSING', '<br>';
 echo "zip: ", extension_loaded('zip') ? 'OK' : 'MISSING', '<br>';
?>
```

The  Output looks like this:

```
GD: MISSING
dom: MISSING
PDO: MISSING
zip: OK
```

even though "php -m" shows the modules are available to the command line interface:

```
# php -m | grep [dgP][oDd]
dom
gd
PDO
pdo_sqlite
wddx
```

. How can I make them available to the web server?

Comment: Maybe you have diffrent php.ini files for cli and webserver?

Comment: Yes you are right. The fix I thought worked, stopped working

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you are using a Virtual Machine from Google, Running Centos 7:

1. Find the php extensions, for instance:

   ```
   # find / -name wddx.so
   /usr/lib64/php/modules/wddx.so
   ```
2. Find the php.ini:

   ```
   # find / -name php.ini
   /etc/php.ini
   ```
3. Edit php.ini and change extension_dir directive:

   ```
   ; Directory in which the loadable extensions (modules) reside.
   extension_dir = "/usr/lib64/php/modules/"
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue, this is what worked for me.

`service php-fpm restart`

Might need to do `service php72-fpm restart` depending on version.

You can run `ps -ef | grep php` to try to understand the service name based on the processes that are running.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me was to install Open SUSE
Then install the php application

`#zyyper-log | grep php
2019-12-24 13:40    449  1.14.33  zypper install php7
2020-03-25 16:19  10705  1.14.33  zypper install php7
php7-mysql apache2-mod_php7
2020-03-31 11:26  26810  1.14.33  zypper install php7-zlib
2020-03-31 13:32  30329  1.14.33  zypper install php7-gd`