# php73-mbstring is installed but not shwoing in phpinfo file and magento websitet is not working

Tags: apache, centos7, fastcgi, php

I have installed a multi PHP version on my centos 7 with FastCGI. after installing some of the extension is missing. I am trying to install it and get success to install it, But Its not showing me on the phpinfo file. 
And my magento2 website goes down for that missing extension.

Does anyone have any idea?
[look at the error which i am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aekiT.png)

Comment: Did you restart Apache or any other server software you use, or restart PHP-FPM.

Comment: Yes I have restart httpd server and php73-php-fpm server so many times but still not working

Comment: The php-mbstring package is not available, I see when I look at the error image

Comment: Looks like you made a typo, the packages should be available try ```yum install php73-mbstring``` or ```yum install php7.3-mbstring```

Comment: Yes I have tried that command and able to install but when I restart the httpd and php73-php-fpm server, but still, it is showing me not enable.

Here are the error images : https://prnt.sc/qlrpz9

Comment: There are all already installed, I see

Comment: See the answer of the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50398060/enable-extensions-for-php-on-centos-7

Comment: I don't get it anymore. I am myself confused a bit now

Comment: I have change the extension_dir, And restat the web server, But still not working :(

Comment: Ok, put it back to normal

Comment: I am not responsible for any damage

Comment: Ill try every thing but i am not able to load modual in webserver.

Answer (score 0):

what's your phpfpm command line parameters?

```
-c : means php.ini file location
-y : means php-fpm.conf file location
```

Don't use wrong parameters !